# how to fetch sysdate month into a variable then print it in oracle

Tags: sql

how to fetch sysdate month into a variable then print it in oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query in your PL/SQL block.

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(current_date, 'FMMonth') AS "Current Month" 
FROM dual;
```